# Can array initializers only be used in a variable or field initializer?

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error:

> Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field initializer.  Try using a new expression instead.

Here is my code:

```
// Declare listbox information array
string [] tablet = new string[]{{"Microsoft Surface  Price: $1,162.99  Screen Size: 10.6 Inches  Storage Capacity: 128 GB"},

                                {"iPad 2 Price: $399.99, Screen Size: 9.7 Inches, Storage Capacity 16 GB"},
                                {"Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Price: $329.99, Screen Size: 10.1 Inches, Storage Capacity 16 GB"},
                                {"NOOK HD Price: $199.99, Screen Size: 7 Inches, Storage Capacity 8 GB"},
                                {"IdeaTab Price: $149.99, Screen Size: 7 Inches, Storage Capacity: 8 GB"}};

//Array of product prices
int [] tabletPricesArray = new int[]{{"$1,162.99"},
                                       {"$399.99"},
                                       {"$329.99"},
                                       {"$199.99"},
                                       {"$149.99"}};
```

I am not really sure what is going wrong. I'm relatively new to C#. Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: Are you trying to create two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: You don't need the inner curly braces. Also, you can't initialize an int with a string. And your prices aren't integer anyway, unless you count in cents. The decimal type is recommended for money quantities.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of issues:

**Problem 1:**

Here you are creating an array of type `int` while providing strings.

```
  int [] tabletPricesArray = new int[]{"$1,162.99",
                                         "$399.99",
                                         "$329.99",
                                         "$199.99",
                                         "$149.99"};
```

**Problem 2:**

An array of type `int` will not hold floating point values such as prices. Instead use `float`, `double`, or `decimal` (for $).

```
    decimal[] tabletPricesArray = new decimal[]{1162.99M,
                                                 399.99M,
                                                 329.99M,
                                                 199.99M,
                                                 149.99M};
```

If you want `tabletPricesArray` to only be used for displaying items as strings (no calculations), then you can use the string array here as well.

**Problem 3:**

You don't need `{ }` in each array element.

Comment: I can't think of anything else that needs to be said.

Answer (score 4):

I hope the following is what you are expecting. I modified the code for you.

```
       // Declare listbox information array
       string[] tablet = new string[]{"Microsoft Surface  Price: $1,162.99  Screen Size: 10.6 Inches  Storage Capacity: 128 GB",
                                      "iPad 2 Price: $399.99, Screen Size: 9.7 Inches, Storage Capacity 16 GB",
                                      "Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Price: $329.99, Screen Size: 10.1 Inches, Storage Capacity 16 GB",
                                      "NOOK HD Price: $199.99, Screen Size: 7 Inches, Storage Capacity 8 GB",
                                      "IdeaTab Price: $149.99, Screen Size: 7 Inches, Storage Capacity: 8 GB"};

       // Array of product prices
       string[] tabletPricesArray = new string[]{"$1,162.99",
                                                   "$399.99",
                                                   "$329.99",
                                                   "$199.99",
                                                   "$149.99"};
```

Comment: Thanks all.  Most of my syntax errors are gone.  Just some minor fixes.

Comment: well, our pleasure.. I would further suggest you to quickly refer some book like "C# 4.0 The Complete Reference" by Herbert Schildt to understand syntaxes. If you are satisfied with any answer, you can make it tick by pressing the tick mark against every answers..cheers..